# Mapbox Navigation SDK - Using Kilometers Instead of Miles

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Quick question - does the Android Mapbox Navigation SDK allow the unit to be changed from Miles to Kilometers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to build this into the SDK in the near future, for now, you will find the `TurfHelper.convertDistance` method useful. [This issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/issues/239) is being used to track progress here.